# Existe forma de consultar todas as publicações feitas removidas?

Tags: debate, suporte, perguntas, respostas

Tal como indica o titulo existe alguma forma de consultar todas as publicações feitas no [SO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com) (perguntas e respostas) que tenham sido removidas pelo utilizador? Acabei a pouco de encontrar esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164340/qual-a-op%C3%A7%C3%A3o-correta-para-se-instanciar-uma-classe-em-php/164343#164343) a qual eu tinha por algum motivo eliminado.

Já tentei ir por [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/48826)(o link não vai funcionar porque está a ir aos meus dados-para funcionar devem passar o vosso id no final) e não mas ai apenas mostra as recentes pelo que me dá a entender.

Afinal existe alguma forma de consultar todas?

Answer (score 8):

Não é possível **pesquisar** suas publicações excluidas sem [10 mil pontos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) de reputação. Pode sim **visualizar** elas mas de maneira individual (precisa saber o id).

Somente com o privilégio de "usuário confiável" (10k de rep) a opção `deleted: yes` tem seu funcionamento habilitado (vide comentários).

> **Vendo posts removidos**
>
> [...]
>
> Você também tem acesso a um novo operador de buscas para encontrar seus >próprios posts removidos: deleted:1.

Caso atenda o requisito de reputração basta digitar o seguinte comando na barra de pesquisa.

```
user:me deleted:yes
```

Comment: era os meus que queria ver apenas, tentei `user:me deleted:yes` mas retorna todas as minhas publicações

Comment: @Tmc esse consulta só mostra as suas publicações, você alguma em especial? pode refinar a pesquisa por tipo ou tag.

Comment: mas não há forma de mostrar apenas as apagadas?

Comment: @Tmc me como mandar um print?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/BV3pk e as publicações que aparecem são todas as que não foram apagadas

Comment: @ramaral você testou (como apareceu?)? pra mim retornou apenas as publicações excluidas do meu usário.

Comment: @ramaral as que estão a aparecer a mim são apenas as NÃO removidas

Comment: @rray Tem razão, após colocar o comentário foi testar e verifiquei que estava errado, daí ter eliminado o comentário.

Comment: é possivel ver na imagem do lado direito por cima da "publicidade" que a pesquisa está a ser feita apenas ao user

Comment: @Tmc a única explicação que encontro é o facto de você ter menos de 10K.

Comment: @ramaral concordo estou pensando o mesmo, quer dizer que eu não consigo ver as minhas próprias publicações?

Comment: @ramaral agora fiquei na dúvida pelo menos as postagens dele deveria ver. Estou tentando testar isso.

Comment: @Tmc consegue ver [essa postagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159890/91) ?

Comment: @rray sim consigo ver

Comment: @rray quer dizer que neste momento só consigo ver as minhas publicações eliminadas se souber quais são?

Comment: @Tmc parece que sim no link da resposta tem: "Você também tem acesso a um novo operador de buscas para encontrar seus próprios posts removidos: `deleted:1`"